# Prove by Pumping Lemma that Language $L=\{a^ib^kc^k : i\geq k\geq 1\}$ isn't Context-Free

Tags: formal-languages, automata, context-free

I'm new to this forum. I have some difficulties on using Pumping Lemma to prove non-CF language.

Let $L=\{a^ib^kc^k : i\geq k\geq 1\}$ and the followings are my attempt.

*Proof*. Suppose by contradiction that $L$ is a context-free language. Let $p$ be the constant given by the P.L. We choose a string $s=a^pb^pc^p$. Assume $s\in L$ and it satisfies properties of a context-free language.
i.e. $s$ can be written as $s=uvwxy$ where $|v|\neq\varepsilon$ and $|x|\neq\varepsilon$. Further $|vwx|\leq q$ and $uv^iwx^iy\in L,\  \forall i\geq 0$.

- If $v$ contains at most one symbol and $x$ contains at most one symbol (e.g. $v=a$, $w=b$, $x=c$.) Consider $s=uv^0wx^0=b\notin L$. And we reached contradiction.
- If $v$ contains more than one symbol or $x$ contains more than one symbol (e.g. $v=ab$, $w=\varepsilon$, $x=ca$.) Consider $s=uv^2wx^2=ababcaca\notin L$. And contradiction reached.

Therefore, the language $L$ is not context-free. Q.E.D.

I'm sure I could have missed important cases, and my confusion raises here as what is a general approach to find all cases that could be contradictions. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have understood the pumping lemma pretty well. All advice you need is to proceed **slowly and carefully**. For example, there is no need to "Assume $s\in L$" since it is a fact. For example, where was $y$ when you reset $s$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thanks. That was some typographical errors.

Comment: "If $v$ contains at most one symbol and $x$ contains at most one symbol (e.g. $v=a$, $w=b$, $x=c$.) Consider $s=uv^0wx^0=b\notin L$" Suppose $p=2$ and $v=a$, what happens? An example is good for understanding, but is generally excluded in proof.